# Using File.ReadAllLines from embedded text file

Tags: c#, embedded-resource, file.readalllines

I have been applying what I have learned so far in Bob Tabors absolute beginners series and I wrote a small console word game for my daughter that requires me to generate a random 5 letter word.

I was previously using `File.ReadAllLines(path)` to generate a string array from a text file (wordlist.txt) on my system and `Random.next` to generate the index I would pull from the array.

I learned from some posts here how to embed the file as a resource but now I am unable to find the syntax to point to it (path). Or do I have to access it differently now that it is embedded?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you'll need to use StreamReader for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I realize my feeble explanation and lack of code example did not help here at all. I looked at that example prior to posting but could only see where it would retrieve a string for me. I have a text file with one 5 letter word on each line (5733 lines) and I needed to get these words into an array of strings. I then generate a random integer and use that as the index of the string to pull from the array. It was working well until I wondered how I could include the text file as part of the final .exe :)

Answer (score 10):

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is impossible to offer specific advice.

However, the basic issue is this: when you embed a file as a resource, it is no longer a file. That is, the original file still exists, but the resource itself is not a file in any way. It is stored as some specific kind of data in your assembly; resources embedded from file sources generally wind up as binary data objects.

How to use this data depends on what you mean by "embed". There are actually two common ways to store resources in a C# program: you can use the "Resources" object in the project, which exposes the resource via the project's `...Properties.Resources` class (which in turn uses the `ResourceManager` class in .NET). Or you can simply add the file to the project itself, and select the "Embedded Resource" build option.

If you are using the "Resources" designer, then there are a couple of different ways you might have added the file. One is to use the "New Text File..." option, which allows you to essentially copy/paste or type new text into a resource. This is exposed in code as a `string` property on the `Properties.Resources` object. The same thing will happen if you add the resource using the "Existing File..." option and select a file that Visual Studio recognizes as a text file.

Otherwise, the file will be included as a `byte[]` object exposed by a property in the `Properties.Resources` class.

If you have used the "Embedded Resource" build option instead of the "Resources" designer, then your data will be available by calling `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(string)` method, which returns a `Stream` object. This can be wrapped in `StreamReader` to allow it to be read line-by-line.

Direct replacements for the `File.ReadAllLines(string)` approach would look something like the following…

**Using "Embedded Resource":**

```
string[] ReadAllResourceLines(string resourceName)
{
    using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
        .GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        return EnumerateLines(reader).ToArray();
    }
}

IEnumerable<string> EnumerateLines(TextReader reader)
{
    string line;

    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        yield return line;
    }
}
```

**Using `Properties.Resources`:**

You can do something similar when using the `Properties.Resources` class. It looks almost identical:

```
string[] ReadAllResourceLines(string resourceText)
{
    using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(resourceText))
    {
        return EnumerateLines(reader).ToArray();
    }
}
```

called like `string[] allLines = ReadAllResourceLines(Properties.Resources.MyTextFile);`, where `MyTextFile` is the property name for the resource you added in the designer (i.e. the `string` you pass in that second example is the text of the file itself, not the name of the resource).

If you added an existing file that Visual Studio didn't recognize as a text file, then the property type will be `byte[]` instead of `string` and you'll need yet another slightly different approach:

```
string[] ReadAllResourceLines(byte[] resourceData)
{
    using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(resourceData))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        return EnumerateLines(reader).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Note that in all three examples, the key is that the data winds up wrapped in a `TextReader` implementation, which is then used to read each line individually, to populate an array. These all use the same `EnumerateLines()` helper method I show above.

Of course, now that you see how the data can be retrieved, you can adapt that to use the data in a variety of other ways, in case for example you don't really want or need the text represented as an array of `string` objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using The Resource file and added a text file you could use

```
string text=Properties.Resources.<ResourceName>
```

here Resources is default Resource for your project .If you have added a custom Resource File you can use its name instead of Properties.Resources

if your content is a file then it is represented as a byte.In your case for simple Text it will be an string if you have included a Text File.

for any other file you can use the syntax for converting content to text(if it is text) as

```
string text=Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Properties.Resources.<ResourceName>);
```

if your file has any other encoding (as UTF Unicode ) you can use UTF8 or such classes for that under Encoding