# C# How to read embedded resource text file with File.ReadLines?

Tags: c#, resources

How can I do that?
My string for hello.txt is:

```
string hello = Properties.Resources.hello;
```

and I want it so:

```
Random rand = new Random();
IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(hello);
var lineToRead = rand.Next(1, lines.Count());
var line = lines.Skip(lineToRead - 1).First();
txtbx_output.Text = line.ToString();
```

This here works for me with no problems:

```
IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"my pathblabla\Text\hello.txt");
```

but not as a resource !

This makes me very angry

Comment: What is the value of `hello`?

Comment: I've added hello.txt as a resource. Inside hello are only two words for example:
hi and hello. Then after clicking one button those words schould appear ... it does not work i this makes me very angry

Comment: Do you **need** to use file.ReadLines?

Comment: resources are compiled binary files, not text.

Comment: `File.ReadLines(string path)`, you need to specify a path, yet you are specifying your `string hello`. If you **need** to use `File.ReadLines()`, then you need to find the path to that resource using reflection.

Comment: use this: `IEnumerable<string> lines = hello.Split(new[] {"\r\n", "\r", "\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);`

Comment: THANK YOU dotctor! That was extacly that was I need!!! THANK YOU!  ;)

Comment: May Allah Bless you dotctor!! :)

Comment: im prety sure that gonna help you :
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910061/using-file-readalllines-from-embedded-text-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910061/using-file-readalllines-from-embedded-text-file)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
string hello = Properties.Resources.hello;
Random rand = new Random();
IEnumerable<string> lines = hello.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, 
                                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
var lineToRead = rand.Next(1, lines.Count());
var line = lines.Skip(lineToRead - 1).First();
txtbx_output.Text = line.ToString();
```